# Android - requestFocus switches keyboard off

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm switching focus from one AutoCompleteTextView to another when the user presses enter on keyboard. The problem is that the keyboard always hides when the next AutoCompleteTextView gains focus. Is there any way to prevent that?
Here's the code that I use to switch focus:

```
field1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        field1.dismissDropDown();
                        field2.requestFocus();

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I haven't used any imeOptions in XML files which declare field1 and field2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, switching focus make the keyboard go away. A quick fix would be to programmatically tell the keyboard to stay visible with:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to show the keyboard programmatically after `requestfocus()`

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//to show keyboard
keyboard.showSoftInput(field2, 0);

//to hide keyboard
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(field2.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to source code of AutoCompleteTextView:

```
    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        // Perform validation if the view is losing focus.
        if (!focused) {
            performValidation();
        }
        if (!focused && !mPopup.isDropDownAlwaysVisible()) {
            dismissDropDown();
        }
    }
```

I think you can delete #field1.dismissDropDown() line - maybe it will be help you.

Moreover I think you should set OnEditorActionListener instead of OnKeyListener. I recommend you to try above code:

```
  field1.setOnEditorActionListener(new AutoCompleteTextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_ENTER) {
        field2.requestFocus();
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To force open:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

To Close:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(_pay_box_helper.getWindowToken(), 0);
```